# how to implement text search functionality like report viewer control search in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview

Kindly let me know how can i implement the search functionality on a gridview the one same like in report viewer control that takes you to the searched text.

I have searched a lot , but no luck.

Any suggestion is welcome.Just need to be pointed in the correct direction.

> UPDATE

Also i just had a quick idea looking at the browsers search , example: press ctrl+f and the browsers find tab appears, works the exact way i want it to . Can i force it to appears on the page, when using the website? OR implement it in the code something like that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution i can think of so far is to run the browser search functionality , CTRL +F .And the search in there works best like a report viewer control going into the gridview and finding out the information for me. To me it suited best for my requirements.Still interested to know of any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the link for quick start :
http://evonet.com.au/gridview-with-highlighted-search-results/

Comment: I had but it only highlights the text , and suppose my searched text is on 1001 row , so its no use to highlight it when i do not see it, what iwanted was a search like in report viewer that takes you to the text and  you can press next next.... It's javascript i think so i am assuming their must be an example  out there...

Answer (score 0):

You can also see the following link:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43018/ASP-NET-GridView-with-search-option-SearchableGrid

Thanks.